# Unable to trigger an Android Activity from RxJava2 chain [Android][RxJava]

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have been trying to write an RxJava2 chain and trigger an Android Activity from this chain. The idea is to get an Observable on which I can publish the result of the activity using an interface callback. Here is the code that I call from my Activity to launch the sso flow.

```
final Disposable disposable = userAuthManager
            .initateSignup(this)
            .map(ssoResponse -> {

                <Do some stuff off the main thread>
                return ssoResponse;
            })
            .subscribe(....)
```

`UserAuthManager.initateSignup(Activity activity)` goes like this:

```
override fun initateSignup(starterActivity: Activity): Single<SSOResponse> {

        return ssoService.startSSO(<someData>, starterActivity)
            .map {
                ....... Some business logic and then returning the response
                // After handling, finally returning the SSOResponse ...
                it
            }
    }
```

Finally `SSOService.startSSO(<someData>, starterActivity)` goes like this:

```
override fun startSSO(oldUserSessionJID: String?, starterActivity: Activity): Single<SSOResponse> {

        val intent = Intent(starterActivity, <MyTargetActivity>::class.java)

        starterActivity.startActivity(intent)

        // The below statement prints `true`
        Timber.d("This is main thread: " + (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()))

        listenableFuture = SettableFuture.create()
        return Single.fromFuture(listenableFuture)
    }
```

In the code above for `startSSO`, I return a `Single` from a `SettableFuture` which I set once I get the response inside the activity. 
**Issue**: `MyTargetActivity` launches with a black screen and nothing renders on it. Also, the debug points inside the activity behave weirdly. Sometimes they work and sometimes they don't. I have tried launching activity by directly calling `SSOService.startSSO(<someData>, starterActivity)` from a button click and it works fine. Also, I was thinking that the issue might be related to activity being launched on a non-UI thread and hence I logged that as well. The activity seems to be launched on a UI thread based on the log statement. What is the problem here?

**PS:** I have removed `observeOn()` and `subscribeOn()` calls to make things simple and assume everything runs on the UI thread.

Comment: if you launch the activity with the same code but ouside an rx chain, would it render properly?

Comment: @Gustavo yes !!